# Apache Flume-Kafka-Sink producer duplicated messages

Tags: apache-kafka, flume

We've meet strange problem with `flume-kafka-sink`, `kafka` broker failed multiple times and producing duplicate messages(every 50 record are same), but the settings about `producer.sinks.r.request.required.acks = 1`, quota to `kafka` documentation "This option provides the lowest latency but the weakest durability guarantees (some data will be lost when a server fails)", It can't be produce duplicate data? Is that means the problem caused by `flume` or `flume-kafka-sink`?

Comment: Where's your data coming from?

Comment: business service log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flume-Kafka-Sink produce messages batch by batch and will retry after some fail write. During some broker fail, some partition leaders can't reach. When a batch write happen, some parition will success, but some failed, when Flume-Kafka-Sink retry, the success part will be duplicated.